# Initial and boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to find the solution of the initial and boundary value problem $$u_{tt}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)=1+\sin x, x \in (0,1), t>0 \\ u(x,0)=\sin x, x \in (0,1) \\ u_t(x,0)=0, x \in (0,1) \\ u(0,t)=\frac{1}{2}t^2, t>0 \\ u(1,t)=\frac{1}{2}t^2, t>0$$

I have done the following:

The charactiristic curves are $x-t=x_0-t_0$ and $x+t=x_0+t_0$.

From Green's identity we have $$\iint_{\Omega} \left (\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{t}}\right ) dxdt=\int_{\partial{\Omega}}Pdx+Qdt$$

We choose $Q=-u_x$, $P=-u_t$.

So, we have $$\iint_{\Omega}(u_{tt}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t))dxdt=\iint_{\Omega}(1+\sin x)dxdt=\int_0^{t_0}\int_{x_0-t_0+t}^{x_0+t_0-t}(1+\sin x)dxdt=\int_{\partial{\Omega}}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)$$

$$\int_{C_1}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)+\int_{C_2}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)+\int_{C_3}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)$$

- $$C_1: x+t=x_0+t_0 \Rightarrow dx=-dt$$

$$\int_{C_1}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)=\int_{C_1}(u_t dt+u_x dx)=\int_{C_1}duu(x_0,t_0)-u(x_0+t_0, 0)\\ =u(x_0, t_0)-\sin (x_0+t_0)$$

- $$C_2: x-t=x_0-t_0 \Rightarrow dx=dt$$

$$\int_{C_2}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)=\int_{C_2}(-u_t dt-u_x dtx)=-\int_{C_2}du=-[u(x_0-t_0,0)-u(x_0,t_0)]=u(x_0,t_0)-\sin (x_0-t_0)$$

- $$C_3: t=0 \Rightarrow dt=0$$

$$\int_{C_3}(-u_t dx-u_x dt)=-\int_{C_3}u_t(x,0) dx=0$$

So, $$u(x_0, t_0)-\sin (x_0+t_0)+u(x_0, t_0)-\sin (x_0-t_0)=\int_0^{t_0}\int_{x_0-t_0+t}^{x_0+t_0-t}(1+\sin x)dxdt \Rightarrow 2u(x_0, t_0)=\sin (x_0+t_0)+\sin (x_0-t_0)+\int_0^{t_0}\int_{x_0-t_0+t}^{x_0+t_0-t}(1+\sin x)dxdt \Rightarrow u(x_0, t_0)=\frac{1}{2}\sin (x_0+t_0)+\frac{1}{2}\sin (x_0-t_0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t_0}\int_{x_0-t_0+t}^{x_0+t_0-t}(1+\sin x)dxdt$$

Is this correct??